# Moodle local folder database update

Tags: mysql, database, moodle

In our `Moodle 2.6` version, we wanted to put some files under `moodle/local/ourfilesdirectory/...`

When we create the folder, without putting files in the directory, Moodle starts to `update` the `database` in admin mode.

Is it with the permissions on the server? And how to create the folder, without to update the database.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle treats subdirectories within the 'local' directory as plugins - when it finds a new subdirectory it tries to install the plugin found there (much like subdirectories within 'blocks', 'mod', 'course/format', etc.).

If you want to create a directory to hold some arbitrary files (and I assume you have a good reason for wanting to do so), you need to put them in a subdirectory that Moodle doesn't expect to look for plugins in.

Here is a full list of the directories where any subdirectories are expected to be plugins:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types

Comment: Is it always this way or just in our case? Because we have de test system also on the same server and there isn't a problem to create new folder under local. And the system doesn't sees it als new plugin.

Comment: When an admin visits the home page (or the 'notifications' page), Moodle scans each of the plugin directories on the site to find new plugins. It also scans the enclosed 'version.php' files to see if there are any existing plugins that need upgrading. This is the standard behaviour that happens on all Moodle site.

Comment: so, what I am misssing ist to include version.php in local/myfolder so the files are taken as a plugin?

Comment: If you want to make them into a proper plugin, then they need a version.php file + correctly-named language file in lang/en/ (with the 'pluginname' string defined). Alternatively, just put the files somewhere else (e.g. 'mylocal/subdir' instead of 'local/subdir', or some other name).